# swift 3 keep bottom tabbar on children windows?

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to keep bottom tab bar in children viewcontroller , my issue when i open children window its open without bottom tabs , how i can keep bottom tabs stuck everywhere in the app ?

this is the class of main tabs window ( landing )

```
class vc_landingPage: UITabBarController , UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

    //Delegate methods
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        print("Should select viewController: \(String(describing: viewController.title)) ?")
        return true;
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let sb2            = UIStoryboard(name: "pools", bundle: nil)
        let v1            = sb2.b_pools.instantiateInitialViewController()!
            v1.tabBarItem     = UITabBarItem( title : "" , image: UIImage(named: "icon-pools-x30"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "icon-pools-x30-active"))

        let sb        = UIStoryboard(name: "myProfile", bundle: nil)
        let v2        = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()!
            v2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem( title : "" , image: UIImage(named: "icon-profile-x30"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "icon-profile-x30-active"))

    self.viewControllers = [v1,v2]

        self.selectedIndex = 1
    }

}
```

Comment: make sure that you cannot set bottom bar hidden from storyboard

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedBaig what do u mean ? where i have to set this value in the parent ?

Comment: i mean that https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140711/4720374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please you must manage the children window in a UINavigationController.

```
let v1            = sb2.b_pools.instantiateInitialViewController()!
let navi1 = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: v1)
let v2        = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()!
let navi2 = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: v2)
self.viewControllers = [navi1,navi2]
```

Comment: its worked , but when i open child window there are no Back button !

Comment: any idea why the back button is not appearing in children window ?

Comment: navi1.isNavigationBarHidden = true 

Then you create your own BarNavigation. Maybe it's a UIView that contains a UIButton back

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure your **BOTTOM BAR** is not **none**, make sure it is not set to any of your view controller or your tab bar controller